# Why sqlite database query returns nothing in python code?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to run this query on my existing and filled database:

```
SELECT queries_left FROM 'queries' WHERE 'user_id' = 12345
```

It runs smoothly on SQLiteStudio and gives the desired integer value.

I want to run this query through python, so I tried the following:

```
def user_status(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT queries_left FROM 'queries' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
```

But calling **user_status(12345)** **returns just `[]`**

So what's the problem?

Note: where **user_id** - some integer that **already exists** in the database

Comment: Can you try once without the quotes around table name and column name?

Comment: Don't use single quotes around column and table names. Use single quotes only for string literals. If necessary use square brackets or backticks for column and table names.

Comment: Also, your query does not *run smoothly* in SQLiteStudio. It returns nothing, as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put single quotes around the table and column names:

```py
def user_status(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT queries_left FROM queries WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
```

Single quotes indicate string literals.  If you do need to escape a table or column name, use double quotes.  The following should also work:

```py
def user_status(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('SELECT queries_left FROM "queries" WHERE "user_id" = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall()
```